# Holding scrollbar freezes win32 console application

Tags: c++, c, windows, console

I wrote this little program to illustrate my problem :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int i = 0;
   while(1)
   {
       std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
       Sleep(1000);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

So this simple program will stop counting if you hold the vertical scroll bar ( to watch back logs or whatever ...).

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Cheers

Comment: Does it do the same thing when you drag it by the title bar? Because it might just be a feature of windows or the console

Comment: Console apps will also freeze if you start selecting text. It's extremely annoying, but I'm afraid it's a "feature" - it would be interesting to see whether this is documented anywhere, though.

Comment: Using a thread doesn't solve the problem either.  It is clearly hitting a lock that's held by the console window handler while the scrollbar is operated.  I doubt there's a workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really. What happens is that holding the scrollbar prevents the application to write any new output to the console, so it eventually blocks on flushing std::cout. This is due to how Windows implements the console and can not be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rely on the continued execution of the program, you could instead calculate `i` based on the time elapsed from the initial program:

```
#include <ctime>

time_t initialSeconds;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  double i=0;

  //Initialise time
  initialSeconds = time (NULL);

  while(1) {
    i = difftime(initialSeconds, time(NULL));
    sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

This will calculate the number of seconds elapsed based on the computers clock.

(Haven't tested this as I'm not on a machine with a compiler)

Comment: My example was to illustrate the problem. My real code is doing network stuff, and this kind of workaround couldn't work.